# passing id's to modals symfony 2.3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

Is there any way to pass id's to modals in symfony 2.3?

here's an example:

```
<a href="{{ path('route', {'id':table.id}) }}" data-reveal-id = "modal" class = "icon" etc.>
```

so first, without the data reveal the icon becomes a link that when clicked, it goes to the action in the route. That's fine since it's working.

```
<div id="modal" class="reveal-modal large">
    <input type="password" id="someid"/>
```

In my modal I have a password input type, I have a jquery that submits this form, my problem is that this time the code doesn't go to the route.

Anyone with answers will be greatly praised. I swear you won't hear me but I WILL be praising you, thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm fairly new to symfony and the 2.3 documentation just vanished from the site so i'm not sure where to get the info I need other than here.

Comment: You mean, when you submit the form via jQuery, The form is not getting submitted to desired `route`?

Comment: yes, that is my problem @Jeet

Comment: If `jQuery` submits the form, you must have set an `action` to the parameter. That action defines where the form should submit.

Comment: Um, how should I do that? or do you mean placing a route in the javascript? @Jeet

Comment: yes, if your `javascript` is in twig, you can place directly. Else define a global js variable in twig and access that in your `.js` file.

Comment: The thing is it gives me an error saying mandatory parrameters are missing ("id"), and I can't place the table.id in the route because for it to work it has to be in a for loop. @Jeet

Comment: Keep the id as an placeholder like `some_id`. later in javascript, replace the `some_id` with your relevant actual `id`. That should solve your issue.

Comment: I did but the thing is I tried to _alert_ the variable but It returned an error well I'll put the code here so you can check if what I was doing was good   
        `var ImageId = $(this).attr('#data-id');
        var url = "{{path('z_avatar_delete',{ 'id': "image_id" })}}"; 
            window.location.href = url.replace("image_id", ImageId );
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        if ($('#DeletePass').val() == 'password'){ 
                window.location.href = url;
                alert(url);
                $( "#Delete" ).submit();`

Comment: 2.3 is not longer supported.  Hence no documentation.  I know you are probably working with legacy code but updating to 2.8 should not be a huge leap.

Comment: um, it's hard to explain but long story short i'm not allowed to update @Cerad

Comment: I have a few questions here, I tried to alert the ImageID in the `var ImageId = $(this).attr('#data-id')` and the results are undefined. I would like to know what is up with that and how to solve it @Jeet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the form 'action' attribute with `setAction`, when you create your form :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
->setAction($this->generateUrl('route',array('id'=>$table->getId())))
->setMethod('GET')
->add('name', 'text')
->getForm();
```

or

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    'my_form_type',
     $entity,
     array('action'=>$this->generateUrl('route',array('id'=>$table->getId()))
));
```

Comment: I would have to change my input type to a form, am I right? so after submission of the form it will redirect to the route? but does the method "GET", gets the id that i'm trying to get?

Comment: I would suggest it yes. Because it will be simpler to use .submit from jQuery.

Comment: I'm getting this error with the mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate route, to be frank I don't get this problem.

Comment: Pass the id to `$this->generateUrl()` (answer updated)

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the passing of the id as array? or rather as string? well if it's possible.

Comment: No. That's also what you do here : `{{ path('route', {'id':table.id}) }}`